# Finding position of (sub) image in parent image in base64 encoded strings

Tags: c#, image, base64

I was hoping someone could help me with figuring out (IF possible) whether the location of an image within a larger image can be determined using their `base64` encoded string representation. If not, what would be the best (quickest) method of finding the sub image within the image. As an example say I created a *50x50* sample image and a *22x12* subimage and converted each of them to a `base64` encoded string, how would I find the location of the subimage?

As a side note. I am working in `C#`.

Comment: How does posting the base64 representation of an image (I assume that's what you've done) help with asking your question? I'd probably just edit it and remove that part. To answer your question, I think you need to do some reading on base64 encoding. Also, you've not stated what image format your image is in.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I guess I should start getting acquainted with base64 representation of images. I know that finding the image is not too difficult using their corresponding Bitmaps. For now an answer such as, this is possible or is not will suffice :-)